# hyperref not working. It goes to wrong page

Tags: hyperref, links

I dont understand why my `hyperref` is not going to the page I wanted when I click it on my table of content?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %times font
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %roman & arabic label page
\usepackage[top=50mm , bottom=50mm, left=45mm, right=45mm]{geometry}

\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
\renewcommand{\contentsname}%
{Table of Contents}% change "Contents" (default) to "Table of Contents"
}

\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
linkcolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{document}
\input{CoverPage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak

\input{TitlePage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak

\input{CopyrightPage}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Copyright}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagebreak

\input{DeclarationPage}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\pagebreak

\input{AcknowledgementPage}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgement}
\pagebreak

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}

\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\pagebreak

% % (1) =========================================
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{1. Introduction}
\input{Introduction}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\pagebreak
```

Comment: Using this way, you have to use a `\phantomsection` before the `\addcontentsline...`, but there might be more issues to solve. `\addcontentsline` should be done before you use `\input` and I would not use `\pagebreak` there. Replace it with `\cleardoublepage`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i just tried.. it's not working.. aikss

Comment: Yes, as I added: There is more work to do, probably. Your document is only a fragment, it's hard to help you. Do the files with `\input` have `\chapter` inside?

Comment: how about this    \tableofcontents
 \phantomsection
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
  do i put    \tableofcontents after the     \addcontentsline.. as well??

Comment: Yes, try that, but there's even a better way. I'll try a solution.

Comment: the files inside the \input has sections and subsections..

Comment: it's working!! thanksss but the rest of the page is working except the table of contents page.. it link to the 1st page..

Comment: As I said, I'll try a solution... just be patient ;-)

Comment: opps haha sorry...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ehh i just changed pagebreak to \cleardoublepage.. everything works!! thanks!! but can i ask why use cleardoubepage instead of page breaks? o.o

Comment: `\hyperref` needs clear page anchors which is 'guaranteed' if the page is cleared of all content and then a new page is shipout, in conjunction with a `\phantomsection` for `\addcontentsline`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the O.P. code...

- Use `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{...}` if some content must be explicitly added to a ToC
- For the **Table of Contents** and **List of Figures** `\usepackage{tocbibind}` is the cleaner solution
- The `Introduction` should be real chapter and not something with `\section` and `subsection`. This screws up the bookmarking etc. and numbering.
- The `\input` is too much for my taste -- It makes editing (and debugging) very difficult.

Some notes on `\phantomsection` etc.

If content is to be added to a `.toc` etc. file, `\addcontentsline{toc}{...}{...}` is most times the right choice. However, if this happens without a `\cleardoublepage` (or `\clearpage`) in conjunction with `\phantomsection`, the link will go to a previous page.

The `\phantomsection` can be omitted however, if a command like `\chapter*` etc. is used. An anchor related to `chapter*` is inserted by `hyperref` then. For more information, see section

> 3.2 Options for destination names

in the `hyperref` manual please.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %times font
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %roman & arabic label page
\usepackage[top=50mm , bottom=50mm, left=45mm, right=45mm]{geometry}

\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
\renewcommand{\contentsname}%
{Table of Contents}% change "Contents" (default) to "Table of Contents"
}

\title{Foo}
\author{Foo}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
linkcolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{document}
\input{CoverPage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\input{TitlePage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Copyright}
\input{CopyrightPage}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\input{DeclarationPage}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgement}
\input{AcknowledgementPage}
\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\cleardoublepage

% % (1) =========================================
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{1. Introduction}
\input{Introduction}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}  % Why???



\end{document}
```

For the individual `FooPage.tex` files I used basically this code

```
\chapter*{Foo}  % To make the page header outstanding, just for this solution
\blindtext[2]
```

Replace `Foo` with the relevant name (Exception: `TitlePage.tex` is `\maketitle` only)

The individual `\phantomsection` commands aren't necessary if `\chapter*` etc is used, but I kept them, since it's unclear what's inside the real `\input{...}` files.

[image]

Comment: so you dont use the phantomsection anymore ah??

Comment: @Michimcchicken: Not everywhere. I'll update my code

Comment: what if i dont use tocbibind ? cause i dont know why the auto download not working..

Comment: btw the setcounter thing at the intro page is because i using different page numbering.. the pages before list of figures are using roman numbering and the introduciton page is using arabic and start from page 1.. haha required by my faculty.. dont ask me haha

Comment: If you use don't use `tocbibind` then you have to use `\addcontentsline`... again. And you are setting the chapter number, not the page number ;-)

Comment: if i set my counter to 1 then it'll become 1.0.1 right?? o.o

Comment: @Michimcchicken: Yes, but you should that before `\input{Introduction}` ;-)

Comment: oooo okayoaky thanks.. then is \setcounter{page}{1} the page number??

Comment: @Michimcchicken: Yes

Comment: 1) please edit your answer at the point of `\end{document}` 2) is `\phantomsection` necessary?

Comment: @touhami: I would say that depends on the files to be input, doesn't it? If I omit it, say before `\input{CopyrightPage}` and remove `\chapter*{Copyright}` in that file, it clearly goes wrong. The `\addcontentsline` will lead to wrong link to the cover page

Comment: you are right here.

Comment: @touhami: Yes, in this case ;-) But thanks for the editing suggest -- the O.P. edited in between and I think the error came in then...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with the particular wrong behavior just in the roman sections. The solution was to put the command \addcontentsline... after the title of roman sections and before in arabic sections.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add some context, detail and/or explanations for how the solution works exactly? Furthermore your answer would be way more helpful if you add some concrete code - even though it might seem "overkill".

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem only for a few sections and found that it was because of float specifier ***h!*** overriding internal parameter. e.g.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
% My graphics
\end{figure}
```

Removing "!" actually solved the problem for me.